# IoC container in all cases? ( against static class )

Tags: c#, ioc-container, static-classes

I am a young developer who starts, I'm just learning Dependency injection and i have a question that torments me.

In my exemple I have a WCF service web (soap), it performs some simple business action and makes a call to the database.

So , my project is cut into

Service -> Business Layer -> Layer Data Access -> Data base

in my case, there is simple business action in business layer and à SELECT statment in data access layer .

So now (certainly wrong way) I used static class to communicate between my layers:

In summary :

Service Layer:

```
public void GetData()
        {
            BusinessLayer.GetData();
        }
```

Business layer :

```
static class BusinessLayer
    {
        public static void GetData()
        {
            //If something or something else ...
            DataAccessLayer.GetData();
        }
    }
```

Data Access Layer:

```
static class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public static void GetData()
        {
            //DO insert in database
        }
    }
```

First, is this a bad way to go?

Then, for this kind of very simple case, is that it is worthwhile to set up an IoC container?

Thank you in advance .

PS: Sorry for my English

Comment: The premise of the question doesn't seem valid. It's not static classes vs IoC container as you don't need an IoC container to do dependency injection.

Comment: Imho it depends more on how and what your company is doing. And how fast do they change the direction of development) There are cases when IoC is usable for a very simple scenarios, there are also cases when IoC is not an option at all.

Comment: This question seems quite broad and thus will be closed probably. You should not care about containers but about your actual design of classes. With `static` you usually mention "stuff that exists independent of an actual instance of a class. However I assume a business-layer has a 1:1-relation to a data-access-layer, doesn´t it? So makie thjis all instances and you´re done.

Comment: [This article](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/) describes when to use a container.

Answer (score 0):

I would make interfaces out of your layer classes. This removes the static classes, as desiried, and sets you up for injection. For your example, which is rather small, I would not recommend going through the trouble unless as a learning experience. There are no hard rules for when to use this injection but the pattern helps tremendously when unit testing comes about.

*Nobody ever said: "Wow! This would have been much easier to write a unit test for if it were a static method or singleton!"*

In the end you will have something along the lines of interface for the functionality you want to inject. This assumes some level of domain model will exist and raw data from the database will be converted into the model.

You would begin by defining the various interface you have to have injected into you dependent classes.

```
public interface IBusinessLayer
{
    Data GetData();
}

public interface IDataAccessLayer
{
    Data GetData();
}

public interface IDatabase
{
    DbData GetDatabaseData();
}
```

The main goal is to have the container inject the funcitonality you to complete the operations desiried. In this, getting data. Assuming you data is a class in the domain model.

```
public class ServiceLayer
{
    IBusinessLayer business = null;

    public ServiceLayer(IBusinessLayer business)
    {
        this.business = business;
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        Data data = business.GetData();
        // do something with data
    }
}
```

You can repeat the same pattern for the different layers. While this seems a lot of work for a simple application the hard edged given by the interfaces allow each layer to evolve on it own ... so long as the interface contract remains.

The segregation is nice if you keep the layers clearly defined. For example, by not letting raw database data, rows etc. bleed up into the upper layers.

public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
    {
        IDataAccessLayer dataAccess = null;

```
    // container will inject data access layer
    public BusinessLayer(IDataAccessLayer dataAccess)
    {
        this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public Data GetData()
    {
        Data data = dataAccess.GetData();
        // do something with data?
        return data;
    }
}

// Retruns typed data business layer
public class DataAccessLayer : IDataAccessLayer
{
    IDatabase db = null;

    public DataAccessLayer(IDatabase db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public Data GetData() 
    {
        var db_data = db.GetDatabaseData();
        Data data = /*convert raw db_data -> type domain data*/
        return data;
    }
}
```